# Verify signature using NIST P-256 type key and SHA-256 algorithm

Tags: java, x509certificate, signature, sha256, ecdsa

I encounter a problem with validation of signature in Java using SHA-256 algorithm and NIST P-256 type key.

I have a X509 certificate (provided by Certificate Authority) which contains a public key and I should certify authenticity of the message that I receive.

Signature that I receive is encoded in Base32 (on 103 characters) and I decode it to binary. I obtain a bytes array of 64 octets.

Informations on public key :

```
Sun EC public key, 256 bits
  public x coord: 76693623628200764797317561328856095594448010045454057728566183687964056347177
  public y coord: 111784915166853162657631137717721670318464358783507947441022826650722573271612
  parameters: secp256r1 [NIST P-256, X9.62 prime256v1] (1.2.840.10045.3.1.7)
```

**(EDIT)** Method that I use to verify authenticity of my message :

```
public static void verify(String message, String signatureReceived, String pathToCertificate) {

    try {

        final X509Certificate certificat = getCertificate(pathToCertificate);
        final PublicKey publicKey = certificat.getPublicKey();

        final byte[] signatureReceivedInBinary = BaseEncoding.base32().decode(signatureReceived);

        byte[] rBytes = Arrays.copyOfRange(signatureReceivedInBinary, 0, 32);
        byte[] sBytes = Arrays.copyOfRange(signatureReceivedInBinary, 32, 64);

        BigInteger r = new BigInteger(1, rBytes);
        BigInteger s = new BigInteger(1, sBytes);

        ASN1Integer asn1R = new ASN1Integer(r);
        ASN1Integer asn1S = new ASN1Integer(s);

        DERSequence seq = new DERSequence(new ASN1Integer[]{asn1R, asn1S});
        byte[] encoded = seq.getEncoded();

        Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withECDSA");

        signature.initVerify(publicKey);
        signature.update(message.getBytes("UTF-8"));

        if (signature.verify(encoded)) {
            System.out.println("Signature OK");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Signature KO");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Main class :

```
public static void main(String[] args)
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, IOException,
        KeyStoreException {

    final String message = "MessageToValidate";
    final String certificatPath = "<PATH_TO_CERTIFICATE>\\public_certificat.crt";
    final String signature = "UBFF4NY7MIXQVUZYMRDRGXBTVWIVMCNP76TN7SA24QUJ4AAHG4WTLA2QZ5TSC54F2OQRMWOAKSHLXJLNHXH4GJPBHBWXBO3PMSDOVZI";

    try {
        Test.verify(message, signature, certificatPath);
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

When I execute my application, I obtain this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.SignatureException: Could not verify signature
    at sun.security.ec.ECDSASignature.engineVerify(ECDSASignature.java:325)
    at java.security.Signature$Delegate.engineVerify(Signature.java:1219)
    at java.security.Signature.verify(Signature.java:652)
    at fr.altes.music.utils.Test.verify(Test.java:56)
    at fr.altes.music.Application.main(Application.java:54)
Caused by: java.security.SignatureException: Invalid encoding for signature
    at sun.security.ec.ECDSASignature.decodeSignature(ECDSASignature.java:400)
    at sun.security.ec.ECDSASignature.engineVerify(ECDSASignature.java:322)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Sequence tag error
    at sun.security.util.DerInputStream.getSequence(DerInputStream.java:330)
    at sun.security.ec.ECDSASignature.decodeSignature(ECDSASignature.java:376)
    ... 5 more
```

Comment: You appear to have an encoding of the number values only, probably fixed size (but it would be good to get documentation on that), not the ASN.1 encoding used by Java JCA (and some others). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36542645/does-openssl-sign-for-ecdsa-apply-asn1-encoding-to-the-hash-before-signing and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45470941/create-asn-1-from-two-big-integers . Alternatively if you can use BouncyCastle's 'lightweight' API see http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/index.html at org.bouncycastle.crypto.signers.ECDSASigner .

Comment: I am not sure abouu Java, but in Windows Capi, it expects the signature a concatenation of r and s and not the Asn.1 structure.